# stating large cardinal axioms in ZF

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice, embeddings

Can I ask whether there is a good reference for how to state the standard large cardinal axioms in the context of $ZF$? My concern is that it seems that the usual proof that embeddings defined from extenders really are embeddings seems to require the axiom of choice.

Comment: In the case of supercompact cardinals Woodin has definition 220 in "Suitable extender models I", reproduced as Definition 3 of Usuba's arxiv paper "Choiceless Löwenheim-Skolem property and uniform definable grounds".

Comment: Yes, embeddings from ultrafilters require choice. This is in the works of Spector from the 1980s and in the works I've been doing with Yair Hayut in the past few years on critical cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How much choice they beg?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: I don't understand that question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, when you say require choice. Do you mean the full axiom of choice, or some weaker kind of choice like countable choice, dependent choice, etc..

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: For a measurable cardinal, you'd need "measure 1 choice", which is the statement that every family indexed by $\kappa$ admits a choice function on a subfamily indexed by a set in the measure. For extenders, I'm not quite sure, but it would be somewhat related to that, since you'd need all the measures to give you elementary embeddings, but you might need a tad more for the directed system to work (although a good chance is that you'd get it without additional assumptions).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, from what I recall is that even what are called Choiceless large cardinals, are in reality not inconsistent with all forms of choice, so perhaps enough choice is preserved to prove that the embeddings Rupert is alluding to are really embeddings, or even perhaps making such a statement might itself be equivalent to some form of weak choice, which might answer Rupert's question.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: I have no idea what that has to do with my comment, or your question, or Rupert's question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, although I don't know how this can be captured in first order logic, but if we can phrase Rupert's intention as "embedding from extender models being true embedding" in a first order logical sentence, then this itself might prove to impose some weak form of choice, by then one cannot state a standard large cardinal axiom whose definition requires embeddings to be true embedding without at least adding that weak kind of choice, so it cannot be formalized in pure ZF, especially in ZF minus that weak form of choice. So, it does provide an answer to Rupert's question.